# How far ahead of time can I make or bake a bread with fruit and honey in it?

Tags: baking, bread, storage-lifetime

I want to make several loaves of a honey-apple challah for Jewish friends for Rosh Hashanah.  However I am going to be out if town for Labor Day weekend.  If I bake some on Saturday night and seal in Ziploc bags and store it in the fridge, will it be fresh enough to deliver the following Wednesday?

Answer (score 4):

Refrigerating bread promotes rapid staling, do you do not want to do that.

However, ironically, breads in general and challah in specific will freeze very well.  You just want to be sure it is well protected against freezer burn.  For a few days, a zip lock bag should do quite well; for longer storage, wrapping tightly in film wrap, and then putting in the zip lock type bag would be better.

Do make sure the bread is fully cooled before freezing.

You can optionally slice before freezing as well, should you want to, which can be convenient.